# error message : Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Tags: react-native, android-studio

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
> 31 actionable tasks: 31 executed
> Note: C:\Users\Bst 305\ReactNativeDsr\android\app\src\debug\java\com\reactnativedsr\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13m 44s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: C:\Users\Bst 305\ReactNativeDsr\android\app\src\debug\java\com\reactnativedsr\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13m 44s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\Bst 305\ReactNativeDsr\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\Bst 305\ReactNativeDsr\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Bst 305\ReactNativeDsr\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:106:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Bst 305\ReactNativeDsr\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!`

You have no devices connected to run the app. Check if your emulator is running or if you are using physical device verify `USB Debugging` is enabled and your device is connected

Comment: I installed Android Studio in my computer... So, Do the device in that sense ?

Comment: Just installing does not do anything you need to launch up android studio and start the emulator which launches an android phone running virtually on your PC.